# First time building a laser. What power do I put in?

Tags: laser-diode, laser-driver

So here's the diode's datasheet.
https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0549/7500/4823/files/LT-LD-465-4100M.pdf?v=1668835492
I don't know what driver to use, but more importantly, what voltage and current do I need to apply to this? I'm guessing that I should put in 4.2 volts, since it's the median between the minimum and maximum of the operating voltage, but I have no idea what current to use??! I see threshold current, forward current, reverse current, what does this even mean? I just need a quick explanation. All I want to know is, how do I figure out what voltage and current, and driver to use from a datasheet?

Comment: Do note that this laser component is not something you just connect to a simple power supply and start blasting a few things. On the vendor's web site the US $600 price tag of the complete system should be a hint of that fact.   A much better (and safer) approach would be to look for a laser diode that comes with an available evaluation board, or at the very least has a detailed datasheet that includes the recommended driver circuitry.

Comment: "If you need to ask, absolutely don't do it!". That particular diode needs a professionally designed circuit and enclosure to be safe to use. Otherwise you'll absolutely injure your vision. It's beyond trivial when playing with such diodes. Even when connected directly to a DC source without a heatsink, they'll last long enough to hurt you. **Even connecting it to a lousy 9V battery will hurt you before the diode gives up.** So... just don't. If you need a laser, buy a module that has the diode, optics, safety shutter, and read laser safety protocols and get proper protection.

Answer (score 4):

You should use a **constant current** driver with a current between about 550mA and several A depending on  how hard you want to drive it (and how good your heat sink is) and the compliance should be 4.8V or greater. And it shouldn't overshoot by too much, even briefly, to avoid permanently damaging the LD.

Forward current is the current in normal operation

Absolute maximum is the "never exceed value" and anything close to that may not be practical in normal operation (3.5A  * 4.8V = 16.8W that has to be dissipated or emitted as light, which is a *lot* from a tiny 9mm**⌀** package. Without a heat sink it will burn up in seconds at currents approaching 3.5A.

Threshold current is the minimum current required for laser action to begin to occur. Depending on the particular sample you have it is somewhere between 300mA and 550mA.

Reverse current probably is the limit on the internal protection diode. You would not normally deliberately reverse bias the LD.

The easiest (and safest) thing would be to buy a LD controller from a commercial supplier. There are also modules available from various suppliers, or you could try to design and build your own (which would be on-topic here, if you get stuck). A simple power resistor would suffice for testing but is very inefficient. For example, you could use a bench supply and a 2Ω 25W series resistor, and slowly bring the voltage up from a few volts until the current reaches your target. Both the resistor and the LD will dissipate a lot of heat. At 2A, about 15W total.

Be sure to take appropriate safety precautions, this LD is capable of burning things, not "only" blinding you permanently.

Answer (score 1):

The max threshold current is 550mA don't go beyond that. You'll need a heatsink to keep it in it's operating temperature range.

That laser puts out 4W of optical power, that would put it in a class 4 category, which means that you could easily break the law or seriously injure someone at those powers levels. I would discourage use of a laser at those powers.

Comment: I appreciate your response, it helps a lot. I understand the safety. I know that I can permanently blind myself if I don't use goggles, and I will be using goggles when using the completed laser. If I understand correctly, I should set the voltage no higher than 4.8 volts, and I'll start out at 4.2 volts, as that's the middle between the min-max, and according to the datasheet, 3 amps. 3 amps, 4.2 volts.